# How do I get the exact information shown in "about" section of a software?

Tags: dll, windows-installer, registry, exe, source-code-protection

I need to find the information shown after clicking on "about" section of a software. I cannot use the registry commands but instead I want to know which particular files contain that information in the software.

For example:
If I click the about section of Visual studio it opens up a dialog box and multiple fields including the version are displayed there. I want to know from where does it get that information and I want to fetch that information outside the software.

What I have tried so far?
I had luck in finding the similar information using powershell commands and vbscript scripts but they give the information from the registry and that information is also not the exact one which the "about" section opens!

I hope my question is clear. In case of any doubts please provide your comments.

Comment: Are you familiar with [procmon.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)? You can at least study what is going on in the process. Maybe [check youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FMpfk8knNQ) for how-to samples.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I wasn't familiar with procmon.exe thanks for that reference but I need the information in a file format or something like that, Moreover the suggestions are not giving the exact information which comes on click of about section.

Comment: So I reiterate @SteinÅsmul that I need to find the mechanism/ script by which I can fetch the exact information which a software fetches on click of about section.